# How to branch and include changes in pending pull request

Tags: git, git-flow

- I've created a pull request which includes a set of changes.
- My next task is dependent on those changes
- The PR may take time to be approved and merged into the release branch
- When I create a new feature branch from my local master, the PR changes are absent

How can I create the new branch to be inclusive of the pending pull request, while not creating issues when I come to push the new PR? For example, I don't want changes from the first PR creating conflicts when I merge the second.

Considered branching from the first feature branch or merging the first feature into the second branch, but not sure which is the better option.

Comment: there are two main points needed to make this more clear. Does word 'dependent' mean you are editing the previously(from the first PR) edited files for the second task? Is there any possibility for your 1st PR work be over-changed?

Comment: the first PR won't change, other than code-review pre-merge. I won't be modifying those files.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Given that

- In PR2, you ***don't*** touch files changed on PR1.

There's absolutely no possibility of merge conflicts between PR1 & PR2.

And if

- PR1 won't change too.

Your approach is perfectly ok & won't affect history too.

In case PR1 get changed and that is a dependent for PR2, addition to your work, you might need to adhere that change in your PR2 implementation (Ex: a dependent method signature). If this is the case, rebasing your current branch(PR2) taking master (or develop, the main development branch into which PR1 has been merged) branch as the base would make your history much nicer. :))

Answer (score 3):

Well, the changes on the second pull request depend on those from the first one. So if (when) you end up changing the first commit, the second one will naturally be affected. This is the whole point of a pull request and why you don't push the code directly to the main repo.

With that said, create your feature branch from the first feature branch and set it as upstream:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=[your remote]/[first feature branch]
```

This way, you keep only the unique, newer commits in the particular feature branch. Running `git status` will then show changes compared to the other feature branch instead of comparing against master.

Every time the first feature branch is changed -- during the time before the PR is approved and it is actually merged -- you run `git pull --rebase` to apply any changes from feature branch one to feature branch two.